# join two tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

So currently i have a relationship between two mysql tabales:
**wp_bp_activity** with "id" and "content" 
and
**wp_bp_activity_meta** with "activity_id" this will match the wp_bp_activity id and "meta_value"
I am trying to output based on the text of wp_bp_activity_meta -> meta_value the wp_bp_activity -> content where wp_bp_activity -> id = wp_bp_activity_meta -> activity_id
Not sure even something like this is possible. I am stuck!
This is the code i have till now:

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_bp_activity_meta WHERE  meta_value LIKE 'test'  ";

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    wp_bp_activity a
        INNER JOIN wp_bp_activity_meta b
            ON CONCAT(a.id, a.meta_value) = b.activity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM wp_bp_activity_meta
INNER JOIN wp_bp_activity
ON wp_bp_activity.if = wp_bp_activity_meta.activity_id
WHERE meta_value LIKE 'test' ";
```